# Dot product in GUSEK/GLPK

Tags: ampl, glpk, mathprog

I've been trying to do a dot product in GUSEK. I used the explicit expression to compute it :

```
sum{i in 1..n} v[i]*x[i]
```

Is there a lighter notation I could use?

Answer (score 0):

GUSEK uses GNU MathProg language which is based on a subset of [AMPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMPL) and AFAIK it doesn't have any special notation for vectors. So I don't think you can further simplify this expression.